# QGIS XYZ Tiles extents / bounds?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, extents, xyz-tiles

I have added a online tile source in the 'XYZ Tiles' option, and added it as a layer, which works fine. But im trying to understand where the extents shown in the layer properties is coming from? When I just loaded a simple JPEG as a raster background, my coord system and extents was just the pixels of the background, and origin 0,0 in a corner. But now with the tile source the origin is the middle (which is not a big deal) but the extents are like (big, see image) it would seem totally disconnected from the actual image widths, which is throwing out my coord system.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates for the zxy tile system are based off of the Web Mercator Projection: 3857. More information on the coordinate system is here:

https://epsg.io/3857

You bounds are covering the whole world, and the width and height are the size of the world, when approximating a sphere.

40075016 meters is basically the circumference of the earth at the equator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_circumference

0,0 in the coordinate system is where the prime meridian meets the equator. Sometimes referred to as Null Island: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense, thanks, is there some way to change this ? Im making a flat fictional game map, so not spherical, and would prefer it say 0-256 for example.